# Spring Boot with with Hibernate: Keep Creating Database when already Exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on this spring boot application with Hibernate. When I run spring boot application, I do not want Hibernate to create the Database or Table when the database or tables already exist. Instead I just want it to get the data from the existed database or use that existed database to insert/update data into it.

**application.properties**

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
db.driver= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = developer
spring.datasource.password = 111111

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

**Image.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Image")
public class Image {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private Long imageNum;

@NotNull(message = "Product image id is required")
@Column(name = "ProductImgID")
private int productID;

@NotNull(message = "Image name is required")
@Column(name = "ImageUrl")
private String url;

Getter and Setter are below

}
```

**BookRepository.class**

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, Long> {

}
```

**BookService.class**

```
@Service
public class BookService {

private BookRepository repository;

@Autowired
public BookService(BookRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

public List<Image> getImage() {
    List<Image> img = (List<Image>) repository.findAll();
    if (img.size() > 0) {
        for (Image ig : img)
            System.out.println(ig.toString());
        return img;
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
 }

}
```

**BookService.class**

```
@Service
public class BookService {

private BookRepository repository;

@Autowired
public BookService(BookRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

public List<Image> getImage() {
    List<Image> img = (List<Image>) repository.findAll();
    if (img.size() > 0) {
        for (Image ig : img)
            System.out.println(ig.toString());
        return img;
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}

}
```

**As you can see on the left side of the image, when I run the application, it automatic add the three columns with no data in it and return the value back to me. **
[image]

**How can I make Hibernate from creating another database, table or columns when there is already an existed one? And just get the existed data from the database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to `none`

[Configure JPA Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties)

> Spring Data JPA already provides some vendor-independent configuration options (such as those for SQL logging), and Spring Boot exposes those options and a few more for Hibernate as external configuration properties. Some of them are automatically detected according to the context so you should not have to set them.
>
> **The spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is a special case, because, depending on runtime conditions, it has different defaults. If an embedded database is used and no schema manager (such as Liquibase or Flyway) is handling the DataSource, it defaults to create-drop. In all other cases, it defaults to none.**